# async/await on graphql query or mutation

Tags: node.js, async-await, graphql

I made API server with **graphql-yoga**. (a nodejs library)

Before searching Google, I just use query/mutation like this.

### [First case]

```
Query: {
    movies: () => { return Movies.all();}
}
```

But after searching I found some code that use await/async on query/mutation.

### [Second case]

```
Query: {
    movies: async () => { return await Movies.all(); }
}
```

By my little knowledge, second case is more safe and better case.

But I'm new at graphql and es6.

Is there any process related async/await already defined in graphql?

Or, do not have to consider about it?

Or, use async/await is better?

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async/await` is an ES6 paradigm **unrelated to GraphQL**.

- It is syntactic sugar supposed to make Promises based code "easier" to read.
- It doesn't provide better performance nor overhead.

**You should keep working with promises until you understand it enough to feel the need for and `async/await` migration.**

Comment: Thanks for reply :)